# AWS Things relation to MQTT topics

Tags: mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I have created several Things and security certificates in my AWS console. I can subscribe and post MQTT messages to `XXXX-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883` without problems. But how to connect Things entity to these MQTT topics? How to treat MQTT messages coming from `Thing1`?

Comment: if you use IoT rule, you can extract the thingName using clientid() sql function (assuming the cliend id you use for mqtt is equal to your thing name in aws iot core). There is no topic to things mapping as based a on policy, each device can publish/subscribe to anything.

Comment: Your questions are not clear. What do you mean by "how to connect Things entity to these MQTT topics", etc? AWS IoT Core has clear rules of what topics a thing publishes to. For a short tutorial that's free if you only want to read, see our AWS MQTT Lab https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/aws/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question how to connect things entity to mqtt topics? You can create different and secured policies in AWS IoT Core and attach them with your "things". Using this you are configuring a singular IoT device or Thing (Not a group of things I assume).

For your second question, You can create AWS IoT rules for treating the MQTT messages from thing1. For example, Define a SQL-like rule query to filter messages from your Thing. For example, you might use

```
SELECT * FROM 'your/topic' WHERE clientId='Thing1'
```

Specify Actions for the Rule:
In the rule configuration, specify actions to be taken when a message from Thing1 matches the rule.

Actions can include storing the message in an S3 bucket or sending the message to another IoT topic/node.